# Event Blocking: how to make some events unavailable to next user

Tags: vb.net

I have made a user control That inherits Windows.forms.Label.

Now what i require is i want to disable some events of Windows.forms.Label to User of that UserControl (Name is LinkLable).

i.e. Label has an Event onPaint. now if some user invokes LinkLable to his form he must not be able to write a code for LinkLable.

Comment: Can you define which events should not be called?

Answer (score 0):

Although I feel it is perhaps not entirely recommended to solve a programming problem this way you can hide events in derived classes like this :

```
Partial Class MyLabel
  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Label

  Public Shadows Event Paint As PaintEventHandler


End Class
```

Then on a form :

```
Public Class Form1


Private Sub Label1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As _
    System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Label1.Paint
        MsgBox("normal label")  '**called
End Sub


Private Sub MyLabel1_Paint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As _
  System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyLabel1.Paint
        MsgBox("my label")  '**not called
End Sub

End Class
```

The above code will show only one message box - the user can add code into the Paint event handler but it will not be called.  You can also implement new behaviour, of course, so that code in the paint handler gets used, but only in whatever new way you design, fully hiding the implementation of the base class.

Comment: Thanks enough to accept the answer, or did this not do what you were after?